# What is the folder location of certificate store in win10?

Tags: windows, powershell, x509certificate, certificate-store

What is the folder path of the certificate store in windows? Meaning, in powershell, I can do something like `cd cert:\localmachine`, is there a way to navigate to this path via file explorer?

My situation: I deleted some cert from localmachine cert store. This included a cert used by windows for login. Because of that I got locked out of that machine. I mounted the hard drive from the locked out vm to another vm and now I can access the files, including the backup of certs I exported before deleting. My goal is to install cert from that backup to the cert store that lies somewhere in the mounted hard drive. The challenge is I haven't been able to figure where the cert store is located in the hard drive to specify it as a part of import-certificate cmdlet.

In powershell, I am doing something like
`import-certificate -filepath d:\users\xxxx\desktop\backup.pfx --certstorelocation whatGoesHere`
for the --certstorelocation, if I use `cert:\localmachine\`, the certificates are going to be installed to the current os, which is not my goal. I want to be able to specify path to cert store that is somewhere in my mounted harddrive.

Comment: you have to import the registry from that machine, the certs are stored there - see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/system-store-locations

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use custom cert store path in Windows, you should import certifates to existing cert stores.

Check [Import-Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/import-certificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

```
cd cert:
PS Cert:\> ls
  Location   : CurrentUser
  StoreNames : {TrustedPublisher, ClientAuthIssuer, Root, TrustedDevices...}
  Location   : LocalMachine
  StoreNames : {TestSignRoot, ClientAuthIssuer, OemEsim, WindowsServerUpdateServices...}

PS Cert:\> cd .\\LocalMachine\
PS Cert:\LocalMachine\> ls

PS Cert:\LocalMachine\> cd .\Root\
```

Thats it :)

Comment: Thank-you but if I import certificates to the location referenced by 'cd cert:', I would be installing certs to the current OS's cert store. I was wondering if there is a way to install a certificate to a cert store that exists in my mounted hard drive from which my computer is not booted.

Comment: It's not possible _in PowerShell_ but it can be done with `CertOpenStore` directly, it allows overriding the registry path. (You still need to mount the other computer's registry hive first.) See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certopenstore